# Updating a Control Within a Currently Open Form

Tags: c#, forms

I am writing a C# Application where I can add various types of students - a normal student, or a academic society student, or a arts and culture society student. On the main form, I have 3 data grids (one lists academic students, one list arts and culture students, and the other lists the normal students). For the user to specify additional information about a student (should they be an academic society student, or an arts and culture student, or both), another form will open up asking the user to add additional Information.

After the information has been specified, I would like to take that information, and add it to the relevant data grid, in other words, update the data grid in the main form.

How I thought I would tackle this idea:

1. Create a method in the main form to add a new entry to the data grid
2. Save the main form object into a Form object
3. Have a method which will will add a new row of data into the form object mentioned in step 2
4. Update the currently open main form with the form object I had saved.

I tried doing the above, and I get the error:

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ONT2000_Practical_05.AcademicSocieties' is less accessible than method 'ONT2000_Practical_05.Form1.addAcademicStudentRow(ONT2000_Practical_05.AcademicSocieties)'   c:\users\okuhle\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ONT2000 Practical 05\ONT2000 Practical 05\Form1.cs    35  21  ONT2000 Practical 05

I have 3 classes - AcademicSocieties, ArtsAndCultureSociety and Student...both AcademicSocieties and ArtsAndCultureSociety inherit the Student class. Below is the code for the classes:

```
THE STUDENT CLASS: 

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ONT2000_Practical_05
{
    public class Student
    {
        private String studentNumber;
        private String studentName;
        private String studentDegree;

        public Student(string number, string name, string degree)
        {
            studentNumber = number;
            studentName = name;
            studentDegree = degree;
        }

        public String getStudentName()
        {
            return studentName;
        }

        public String getStudentNumber()
        {
            return studentNumber;
        }

        public String getStudentDegree()
        {
            return studentDegree;
        }

    }
}
```

THE ACADEMICSSOCIETY CLASS:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ONT2000_Practical_05
{
    public class AcademicSocieties : Student
    {
        private String courseCode;
        private String societyName;

        public AcademicSocieties(String studentName, String studentNumber, String studentDegree, String courseCode, String societyName) : base(studentNumber, studentName, studentDegree)
        {   
            this.courseCode = courseCode;
            this.societyName = societyName;
        }

        public String getCourseCode()
        {
            return courseCode;
        }

        public String getSocietyName()
        {
            return societyName;
        }
    }
}
```

THE ARTSANDCULTURE SOCIETY CLASS

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ONT2000_Practical_05
{
    class ArtsAndCultureSociety : Student
    {
        private int experienceLevel;
        private int competitionWins;
        private String societyName;
        private Boolean colours;

        public ArtsAndCultureSociety(int level, int wins, string societyName, String studentNumber, String studentName, String studentDegree) : base(studentNumber, studentName, studentDegree)
        {
            experienceLevel = level;
            competitionWins = wins;
            this.societyName = societyName;
        }
    }
}
```

THE MAIN FORM:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ONT2000_Practical_05
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void academicSocietiesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void degreeLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void exitApplicationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        public void addAcademicStudentRow(AcademicSocieties thisStudent) //This is where the Error Occurs
        {
            academicSocietiesDataGrid.Rows.Add(thisStudent.getStudentName(), thisStudent.getSocietyName(), thisStudent.getCourseCode());
        }

        private void addStudentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String studentName = ProgramFunctions.validateTextBoxData(studentNameTextBox);
            String studentNumber = ProgramFunctions.validateStudentNumber(studentNumberTextBox);
            String studentDegree = ProgramFunctions.validateTextBoxData(degreeTextBox);

            if (studentName.Equals(null) || studentNumber.Equals(null) || studentDegree.Equals(null) || studentDegree.Equals("null")) //Error 1 is on this line
            {
                ProgramFunctions.displayMessage("Data Integrity Error", "As a result of one or more fields failing data validation, this application will not continue processing data");
            } else
            {
                if (artsAndCultureCheckBox.Checked && academicCheckBox.Checked)
                {
                    Student newStudent = new Student(studentNumber, studentName, studentDegree);
                    StudentData.setCurrentStudent(newStudent);
                    ProgramFunctions.saveCurrentForm(this);
                    GeneralStudentSocietyForm generalForm = new GeneralStudentSocietyForm();
                    generalForm.Visible = true;
                    generalForm.Focus();

                } else if (academicCheckBox.Checked)
                {
                    Student newStudent = new Student(studentNumber, studentName, studentDegree);
                    StudentData.setCurrentStudent(newStudent);
                    ProgramFunctions.saveCurrentForm(this);
                    AcademicSocietyForm academics = new AcademicSocietyForm();
                    academics.Visible = true;
                    academics.Focus();     
                } else if (artsAndCultureCheckBox.Checked)
                {
                    Student newStudent = new Student(studentNumber, studentName, studentDegree);
                    StudentData.setCurrentStudent(newStudent);
                    ProgramFunctions.saveCurrentForm(this);
                    ArtsAndCultureForm artsAndCulture = new ArtsAndCultureForm();
                    artsAndCulture.Visible = true;
                    artsAndCulture.Focus(); 
                } else
                {
                    Student newStudent = new Student(studentNumber, studentName, studentDegree);
                    StudentData.addNewStudent(newStudent);
                    ProgramFunctions.displayMessage("Student Added", "A New Student has successfully been added to the database. Click OK to continue");

                    studentDataDataGird.Rows.Add(newStudent.getStudentName(), newStudent.getStudentNumber(), newStudent.getStudentDegree());
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProgramFunctions.addNewAcademicSociety("Accounting Society");
            ProgramFunctions.addNewAcademicSociety("Law Student Society");
            ProgramFunctions.addNewAcademicSociety("Science Student Society");
            ProgramFunctions.addNewAcademicSociety("Information Technology Student Society");
            ProgramFunctions.addNewAcademicSociety("Business Science Student Society");

            ProgramFunctions.addNewArtsAndCultureSociety("Choir Society");
            ProgramFunctions.addNewArtsAndCultureSociety("Hip Hop Society");
            ProgramFunctions.addNewArtsAndCultureSociety("Anime Society");
            ProgramFunctions.addNewArtsAndCultureSociety("The Hockey Society");
        }

        private void studentDataDataGird_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void academicSocietiesDataGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

THE PROGRAMFUNCTIONS Class (This is where I am saving the Form Object):

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ONT2000_Practical_05
{
    class ProgramFunctions
    {
        private static List<String> academicSocieties = new List<String>();
        private static List<String> artsAndCultureSocieties = new List<String>();

        private static Form1 formObject;

        public static void saveCurrentForm(Form1 formData)
        {
            formObject = formData;
        }

        public static void academicStudentDataGridRow(AcademicSocieties newStudent)
        {
            formObject.addAcademicStudentRow(newStudent);
        }

        public static Form1 updateMainForm()
        {
            return formObject;
        }

        public static void addNewAcademicSociety(String societyName)
        {
            academicSocieties.Add(societyName);
        }

        public static void addNewArtsAndCultureSociety(String societyName)
        {
            artsAndCultureSocieties.Add(societyName);
        }

        public static void displayMessage(String title, String Message)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Message, title);
        }

        public static String validateTextBoxData(TextBox thisTextBox)
        {
            if (thisTextBox.Text.Equals(null) || thisTextBox.Text.Equals("") || thisTextBox.Text.Equals(" "))
            {
                displayMessage("Empty Data Detected!", "You may not specify empty data for the student");
                return null;
            } else
            {
                thisTextBox.Text = thisTextBox.Text.Trim();
                thisTextBox.Text = thisTextBox.Text.ToUpper();
                return thisTextBox.Text;
            }
        }

        public static String getSelectedItem(ComboBox thisComboBox)
        {
            return thisComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

        public static int getArtsAndCultureCount()
        {
            return artsAndCultureSocieties.Count;
        }

        public static int getAcademicSocietyCount()
        {
            return academicSocieties.Count;
        }

        public static String getAcademicSociety(int index)
        {
            return academicSocieties[index];
        }

        public static String getArtsAndCultureSociety(int index)
        {
            return artsAndCultureSocieties[index];
        }

        public static String validateStudentNumber(TextBox studentNumberTextBox)
        {
            if (studentNumberTextBox.Text.Equals(null) || studentNumberTextBox.Text.Equals("") || studentNumberTextBox.Text.Equals(" "))
            {
                displayMessage("Empty Data Detected!", "You did not input any data...Please be sure you do specify some data");
                return null;
            } else
            {
                if (!studentNumberTextBox.Text.StartsWith("s"))
                {
                    displayMessage("Invalid Student Number", "You have entered an invalid student number. Please be sure this student number follows the correct format. The student number must begin with a 's' character. ");
                    return null;
                }

                if (studentNumberTextBox.Text.Length != 10)
                {
                    displayMessage("Invalid Student Number", "The student number specified may not be longer than 10 characters");
                    return null;
                }

                return studentNumberTextBox.Text;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Way way way too much information. Can't you just say what's wrong and give us only the relevant code?

Comment: add your Form1.Designer.cs in question

Comment: Thanks for the tip... I opened the Form1.Designer and I changed the needed form control objects to public

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you are missing the access modifier 'public' in some of your class definitions? If you don't add public before ArtsAndCultureSociety, it will be private.

Answer (score 0):

change the access modifier of the class ProgramFunctions,ArtsAndCultureSociety  to public.